# Concatenate multiple tags from a .xml file using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, concatenation

I want to concatenate multiple tag values from a xml file using JAVA.
The .xml looks like this:

```
<test>
    <testcase>
        <teststep> row 1 </teststep>
        <teststep> row 2 </teststep>
        <teststep> row 3 </teststep>
        <title> Frist Test </title>
    </testcase>
</test>
<test>
    <testcase>
        <teststep> row 20 </teststep>
        <teststep> row 10 </teststep>
        <teststep> row 30 </teststep>
        <title> Second Test </title>
    </testcase>
</test>
```

And the result should be like this:

```
row 1 row 2 row 3
row 10 row 20 row 30
```

There should be 2 variables.

I've tried:

```
NodeList nodeList5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("teststep");
for (int x = 0, size = nodeList5.getLength(); x < size; x++) {
    description = description + nodeList5.item(x).getTextContent();
}
System.out.println("Test Description: " + description);
```

But all I've got is: row 1 row 2 row 3 row 10 row 20 row 30, only one variable.

Comment: The code you've attempted is JavaScript. To process XML in Java, don't reinvent the wheel - lookup JAXB and JAXP.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the required data by first selecting the `testcase` nodes and then select out all the child `teststep` nodes in them

```
NodeList testcases = doc.getElementsByTagName("testcase");
for(int i = 0; i < testcases.getLength(); ++i) {
  Node testcase = testcases.item(i);
  NodeList teststeps = testcase.getChildNodes();
  for (int j = 0; j < teststeps.getLength(); ++j) {
    if(teststeps.item(j).getNodeName().equals("teststep"))
      System.out.print(teststeps.item(j).getTextContent());
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final String data = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final CheckedIterator<Element> it = simple.iterateDom(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(UTF_8)));
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", selectTestStep(it.next().children.get(0).children)));
}

private static List<String> selectTestStep(final List<Element> elements) {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Element e : elements)
        if (e.name.equals("teststep"))
            list.add(e.text);
    return list;
}
```

Will output:

```
row 1 row 2 row 3
row 20 row 10 row 30
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```